# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/connect/header/ConnectHeaders

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am trying to create a connector using debezium connector to postgresql and kafka connect. But am seeing this error

```
[2020-12-31 21:52:20,251] ERROR Producer failure (io.debezium.pipeline.ErrorHandler:31)
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/connect/header/ConnectHeaders
ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=test-connector-poc-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:172)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: An exception occurred in the change event producer. This connector will be stopped.
        at io.debezium.pipeline.ErrorHandler.setProducerThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:42)
        at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:117)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/connect/header/ConnectHeaders.
```

I tried testing the status of the connector. It says status failed with the same error as above.

Comment: What version of Kafka did you download?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am using kafka_2.11-1.0.2.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for the tip. I upgraded to kafka_2.13 and this error was fixed automatically.

Comment: 2.13 is not a Kafka version; it's the Scala version. You upgraded from 1.0.2 to something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect Headers were added in Kafka 1.1.0 with KIP-145

According to the comments, you're using Kafka 1.0.2